# How to validate input from form in struts2 action

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2

I have a jsp with a struts2 form that has a input widget of type number, if I empty this widget and then submit to the form, in struts (before my validation method) I get this in the debug logging:

```
19:10:30,734 ERROR [com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.error:34] Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'someDto.intCol' on 'class mypackage.MyAction: Error setting expression 'someDto.intCol' with value ['', ]
```

I would like to capture this exception (the "Unexpected Exception") do something and then in the validator (in the action) setup the errors with addFieldError from the ActionSupport class,

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT:**

The dto class:

```
public class SomeDto() {

    private Integer intCol; //{with getters&setters}
```

The problem is that when the user clear the input in the Form (in the jsp), struts try to convert [''] (or String empty in others words) to an Integer with the ParametersInterceptor class (like in the log line up).

So, the dto has the getters and setters.

Comment: what the datatype of intCol variable ?

Comment: For this purpose you need another params interceptor. You need to post MCVE, because without it the question is off-topic.

Comment: You are missing the setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "ParameterAware" interceptor:

```
@Override
public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> parameters) {
    System.out.println("parameters: " + parameters);

    if (parameters.get("someDto.intCol")[0].length() == 0) {
        parameters.put("someDto.intCol", new String[]{"0"});
    }
}
```

This will catch the param from the jsp and if if empty will put 0 instead,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As mention by @RomanC If you look at `ParametersInterceptor` around line 299, you find this loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : acceptableParameters.entrySet()) {
            String name = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            try {
                newStack.setParameter(name, value);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                if (devMode) {
                    notifyDeveloperParameterException(action, name, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is where the exception happens and you see the log message. You can extend `ParametersInterceptor` and do what you want. For example, you can put some parameter in `ValueStack` and then use it in you `action`.

But it seems very tricky too me. You may find another way to solve your problem instead of dealing with this interceptor code directly. For example converting the `intCol` to `String` and use validators.